# how to create new contacts using xero api?

Tags: xero-api

how to create new contacts in Xero using API?

i have tried this API  - https://api.xero.com/api.xro/2.0/Contacts but i always get this error : "oauth_problem=consumer_key_unknown&oauth_problem_advice=Consumer key was not recognised."

I don't know how to pass client id and client secret or access token in API?

passing parameter in the header is not working -

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
                "Authorization: Basic " . base64_encode('75F16AECC7F749E08D1822B32CD110EB:lJ_h1cG7dvE5xIAXDWyFDcmGQPqtZOlHzfAzw0ImdLPKOxL5'),
                'Content-Type: application/json'
            ]);

please help

Comment: It looks like you've included your client id & secret in your question. Please be sure to delete and recreate your client to prevent unauthorised access.

Comment: it is not real client id and secret

Answer (score 1):

Xero uses the OAuth2 authorization flow. Broadly speaking, you'll need to:

- Send the Xero user to an authorising URL with your client id, which will result in the user being redirected to your specified redirect uri with a code
- Swap this code for an access token using your client id and secret
- Use the access token as a bearer token in your authorization header when you're making your request to the contacts endpoint

The full details are described in the [Xero Developer docs](https://developer.xero.com/documentation/oauth2/auth-flow).

Comment: i have followed all the steps mentioned in https://developer.xero.com/documentation/oauth2/auth-flow. i got the access token and refresh token. used the access token as a bearer token in your authorization header. also added xero tenant id in header but always showing the same error.

Comment: Can you post your updated curl request using the token? Is the error response exactly the same?

Comment: curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
        "Authorization: Bearer 1fbc811357a1...",
        'Content-Type: application/json',
        'xero_tenant_id: 66f9473f...'
]);

Comment: i have used this one but shows the same error.

oauth_problem=consumer_key_unknown&oauth_problem_advice=Consumer%20key%20was%20not%20recognised

Comment: If you're getting a `consumer_key_unknown` error, your bearer token is not being set properly (and your request is going through to the old OAuth1.0a endpoint, rather than the OAuth2 endpoint). That's the direction you should investigate in.

Comment: i don't know what's wrong. now I'm using Xero SDK and its working fine. anyway, thanks for your suggestions.